# What is best to do? Buy a dual band router & hard wire it into the existing modem/router or buy a wifi signal booster/extender?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I just upgraded to a dual band gigabit modem/router via my cable provider. I have 2 rooms that need a faster & more reliable signal. I want to receive the fastest download speed. What is best to do? Buy a dual band router & hard wire it into the existing modem/router or buy a wifi signal booster/extender?

Comment: Why not buy a WAP and connect it to your current network? The idea behind WAPs is that you can place them where they are needed.

Comment: The fastest and most reliable signal will be through a network cable.  Use a cable instead  ! (you did say you wanted the fastest download speed...)

Answer (score 1):

Signal extenders are usually a last-case option. They can be unreliable, add a lot of latency, and should be avoided where possible (however, avoiding them is not always possible).

I would be buying a proper dual-band WiFi router (802.11ac), *disable* whatever crazy WiFi is on whatever glorified piece of plastic and silicone your cable provider has given you, and just use the 3rd party device exclusively. Plug the WAN port of your WiFi into a LAN port of your cable modem and never touch the cable modem ever again.

Note that disabling the WiFi on the Cable modem is usually something I do so that the WiFi is a) not confusing to guests, and b) not hogging up valuable WiFi spectrum with whatever channel it's hard-coded to using and probably overlapping with something else.

<sup>Subtext: I hate cable modems that ISPs give you because they over charge for the cheapest thing they can get, and I typically only ever use them as glorified media converters. This isn't something I would generally recommend to everyone, but I certainly never use their wifi unless it's like a studio or 1br apartment</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your help. I agree that a 3rd party modem is better in quality. It's a room mates cable account.  I wasn't sure about it.